# Authenticate with SharePoint 365 via CSOM using an API Key

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying to build a MSSQL 2014 SSIS Package to update our SharePoint Online Term Store using CSOM.
The SSIS package operates in the same fashion as a Console Application.

I would like to be able to authenticate with SharePoint via an API Key rather than using a User account and having the credentials within the solution.
I have come across a couple of ways of doing this, but it appears that all of the methods have prerequisites like the project being an MVC project or a SharePoint solution.
These project types include libraries which seem unavailable to Console Applications.

One method which I had some hope for was creating a Web Application in the Azure AD dashboard and add permissions for SharePoint Online.
After creating the AzureAD application I have tried to use an Authentication token which I collected by using `AzureAdAuthentication.cs` from the `AzureAD.GroupMembership.Console` example.

```
ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(@"https://[TENANT].sharepoint.com/");
cc.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(context_ExecutingWebRequest);

static void context_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) {
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Bearer {0}", AzureAdAuthentication.AcquireApplicationToken());
}
```

With no luck. Is there a better way of getting the AzureAD token? Or getting the correct token and providing it to SharePoint?

Have I missed something completely obvious?

Comment: Don't know if it may be of any use, but have a look at [this blog post](http://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/) anyway. Maybe some of the info it provides can prove useful. In case I misinterpreted your requirement, please just ignore my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article, together with associated sample project, should provide you all details for your exact scenario: on how to allow AppOnly calls in a high trust scenario; retrieving the access token via AAD

[Performing app-only operations on SharePoint Online through Azure AD](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2015/05/03/performing-app-only-operations-on-sharepoint-online-through-azure-ad.aspx)

Comment: it was premature celebration. With the method discussed in the blog post I receive a Token which authenticates me. But i am unable to write to the Term Store. The "Permissions to other applications" seems to be ignored, I can have 0 applications defined and I am able to authenticate and read the Term Store. And if I add "Office 365 SharePoint Online" with application permissions or delegate permissions set i am still unable to write to the Term Store. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, writing taxonomy isn't supported (yet) with AppOnly policy: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/7062007-provide-the-ability-to-write-to-managed-metadata-v

Comment: Ah, that would be why. Do you know of any other way I can accomplish this?